# Trying to print a specific part from a json url

Tags: php, json, echo, file-get-contents

I am trying to grab the `"price"` of Bitcoin using the script below. Essentially it visits the coinmarketcap api and prints out the price of bitcoin. However, I am unsure as to what this error means or how I can fix it

---

My code

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/";

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$decode_content = json_decode($contents);

$myprice = $decode_content->data->1->name;

echo "Price: " . $myprice;

?>
```

---

Error msg

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` has an optional parameter `bool $assoc`:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative
>   arrays.

-> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: In addition to this comment:
It will return the object as a array so you have to access it like:
 `$decode_content['data']['1']['name'];` instead of `$decode_content->data->1->name`